# Modifying apsrev.bst file?

Tags: bibliographies, revtex

I would like that my references for which I use `apsrev` show the title of the article. I've found [here](http://www.ualberta.ca/~ichiki/misc/index.html) apsrev-title.bst file that should allow me to do so. But this doesn't work :\

I've downloaded this .bst style, put it in revtex folder where .bst files are, but I get the error

```
I couldn't open style file apsrev-title.bst
---line 38 of file diplomski.aux
 : \bibstyle{apsrev-title
 :                       }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file diplomski.aux
```

So what am I doing wrong? How to implement this? I also looked at .diff file but I don't know what to do with it.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: You didn't refresh the file name database, probably. Try with `apsref-title.bst` in the same directory as your file. What TeX distribution are you running?

Comment: Yep I didn't refresh the fndb in miktex the first time. Now I did it and it works :) Thanks!